# Method that exists...does not?

Tags: java, classpath, guava, nosuchmethoderror

Code (which compiles):

```
    for (Method m : ImmutableList.class.getMethods()) {
        System.out.println(m);
    }

    ImmutableList.copyOf(Arrays.asList(new PlayerLevel[0]));
```

Output (annotated and shortened):

```
public final void com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.add(int,java.lang.Object)
----> public static com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(java.lang.Iterable)
public static com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(java.util.Iterator)
                 (lots of other methods)

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(Ljava/util/Collection;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableList;
```

Huh?

(If the logs are not clear enough, I get an error saying that `ImmutableList.copyOf(List)` is not a method, but by looping through all the methods I see there is a `copyOf(Iterable)`, and `List implements Iterable`.)

Comment: Aren't the function signatures different?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore `List` implements `Iterable`. The code compiles fine anyway, and while I don't think there's a difference between `ImmutableList` at compile time and runtime, I did this check just in case.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace please?

Comment: The following compiles and runs fine for me with Guava 10.0.1: `ImmutableList.copyOf(Arrays.asList(new String[0]));`

Comment: @MatthewFarwell Unfortunately that has no info. The first line in the stacktrace is the line that says `ImmutableList.copyOf(...);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both methods are *compatible at compile time*. But runtime is another beast. I assume, that your code compiles against an older version of Google Collections but runs against a newer version.

**Edit**: 
What happens in detail:

Given the lines

```
List<String tmpArray = Arrays.asList(new PlayerLevel[0]);
ImmutableList.copyOf(tmpArray);
```

the compiler starts to look for a suitable method in `ImmutableList` with the name `copyOf` and one parameter *compatible* to the static type `List<String>`. The version of the class visible to the compiler offers exactly one match:

```
ImmutableList.copyOf(Collection<T> arg0);
```

Please note, that the compiler is *not* interested in the *actual* type of `tmpArray`, only the *static* type (aka. "formal type") is considered.

The compiler writes the *signature* of the selected method into the class file.

At runtime the classloader / linker reads the class, finds the *signature* of the method

```
ImmutableList.copyOf(Collection<T> arg0);
```

and performs a *lookup* (not a *search*!) on `ImmutableList` for exactly the given signature. *Compatibility* does not matter here, that was the job of the compiler. You get the same results, if you use reflection like this:

```
ImmutableList.class.method("copyOf", Collection.class);
```

In both cases Java simply performs a lookup using *exactly* the given type. It does not perform a search like "return method(s) which can be called with the given type".

In your case the runtime classpath and the compile time class are different. So the classloader / linker fails to perform the lookup.

*One step back*

This issue shows the different levels of compatibility:

- *Binary compatibility*: Throw in a new jar and that's it.
- *Source compatibility*: You have to compile your source but you don't have to change it.
- *Behavioural compatibility* or *Semantic compatibility*: The client code must be changed.

You can use these keywords to look around this site or on Google for more infos. A good reference for binary compatibility are the three parts of [Evolving Java-based APIs](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Evolving_Java-based_APIs).

Comment: I have some code where I compile against a newer version of a jar than the one in use at runtime which works fine, although it's not ideal. I'm not sure I understand why different versions matter as long as the method contract is compatible, which it does seem to be from the output. Although I guess there could be some change in something that isn't printed out.

Comment: @Thor84no it depends how you define 'compatible'. Are they the same?

Comment: I don't think they're different at runtime, but to make that sure I did this test, which shows that the method I want is there.

Comment: @MatthewFarwell So if `method(Dog)` changes to `method(Animal)` it's incompatible also? I guess that may be key to a solution.

Comment: Turns out I had both Guava and Collections in `ivy.xml` (dependency list). Apparently the compiler prefers Guava and the runtime prefers Collections.

Comment: In that case you have to clean your compile time classpath _and_ the runtime classpath to contain only one Google-Collect jar. Otherwise this issue will be only the tip of the iceberg containing more subtle bugs.

Comment: Yes I removed the Collections entry. Nice expansion of the answer btw. I figured it out myself already, but it'll be good for the next visitor of this question.